# Concurrent conflated queue and listeners

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

I have an `EventsManager` that receives events from an external source. An `Event` has a `type` and a `value`.

Listeners can be registered to the `EventsManager` to be informed of the succesive values of a certain type of event.

The `EventsManager` promises two things, for a given type of Event:

- the same value will not be sent twice in a row (when listeners get notified, they are guaranteed that the value they receive is a different value from the previous notification).
- the order in which values are received from the external source must be preserved, for a given type of event.

I have a working `synchronized` version but I would like to improve the throughput.

Typical use: < 1k listeners, < 10k event types, < 1M events received per second (but most are discarded because there is no listener registered for that type of event or the value has not changed).

- What would be the most efficient strategy to implement that behaviour (for example I could use one queue / lock per event type and hold them in a ConcurrentMap but having 10k queues doesn't sound like a good idea)?
- Are there any existing libraries that would do something like that using scalable concurrent structures?

Example: Listener `lst1` wants to listen to events of type `type1`
The EventsManager receives:

```
event: type2, value: 2
event: type1, value: 1
event: type1, value: 1 //no change => discard
event: type3, value: 4
event: type1, value: 7
```

`lst1` should receive, in that order: `1` (only once) then `7`.

Comment: Do the event types have any logical grouping / commonality?

Comment: Forgot to add, what is the current throughput and what is expected?

Comment: You can assume that different event types are independent. Say one type is the speed of the car and the other one the outside temperature. Current throughput is around 200k events per second with the synchronized version.

Comment: Not sure if useful but there was a JavaSpecialists newsletter recently covering a [Striped Executor](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue206.html) that may be of interest.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon That looks promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to implement this event flow

1. All incoming events are put into an initial **EventQueue**
2. An **EventDispatcherThread** reads the EventQueue, and **filters and routes** the events into appropriate **EventQueue** for each type (simple map of queues)
3. Multiple instances of **EventListernerThread** are reading the appropriate EventQueue of its type...

no locks/synchronisations are needed

Comment: This seems like it would scale in the most awful way possible.

Comment: @Woot4Moo On the other hand it saves a lot of context switching.

Comment: @assylias sure i could see that, however the issue i do see is that the `EventListenerThread` as described in step 3 could cause duplicate work to be performed, because that does not preclude having to use synchronization.  Or at the very least a concept of load balancing.

Comment: @Woot4Moo Of course if does not preclude anything since its up to you to decide. I think "no synchronisation needed" is enough hint. :) Meantwile it should be well-known that synchronisation is a performance killer. I hope I do not need to mention thread pools...

Answer (score 1):

This answer will change as comments are added.

**IF** you have control of the external source, the quickest improvement is to prevent that source from sending messages that are guaranteed to be discarded / ignored.  For example, the external source could keep a `Map` or some other data structure that allows quick lookups + updates .  The external source would be able to determine what information it would need to send to your `EventQueue`

**IF** you do **not** control the external source, it should be possible that the queue will hold a generic `Event` as you have stated in your original post.  I would recommend adding a `Radix Tree` that is fed from your `Queue`.  What I mean by that is store the values that the queue generates inside a [radix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree#Lookup) .  This allows for the following:

> Unlike balanced trees, radix trees permit lookup, insertion, and
>   deletion in O(k) time rather than O(log n). This doesn't seem like an
>   advantage, since normally k ≥ log n, but in a balanced tree every
>   comparison is a string comparison requiring O(k) worst-case time, many
>   of which are slow in practice due to long common prefixes (in the case
>   where comparisons begin at the start of the string). In a trie, all
>   comparisons require constant time, but it takes m comparisons to look
>   up a string of length m. Radix trees can perform these operations with
>   fewer comparisons, and require many fewer nodes.

**UPDATE**

**Question:**

> Do you know of a thread safe implementation of a radix tree?

[Concurrent Trees](http://code.google.com/p/concurrent-trees/)  Have not tested these!

[API: ConcurrentRadixTree](http://concurrent-trees.googlecode.com/svn/concurrent-trees/javadoc/apidocs/com/googlecode/concurrenttrees/radix/ConcurrentRadixTree.html)

Comment: I have no control over the external source unfortunately. So I need to do the filtering at my end.

Comment: @assylias I have provided a link to a concurrent implementation of the Radix Tree, I have not tested this, so buyer beware :)